# Bar chart to compare data of various fields

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I am trying to compare different fields of two different models and the acceptable value for each field is different i.e., one field can take a million as a value while another field can take 100 as the maximum value. I want to compare all the fields in the same bar chart.

```
       field1  | field2  | field3
Mod1 | 468     | 28,000  | 800,000,000
Mod2 | 162     |  2,000  | 228,000,000
```

I am thinking of taking the percentage of Mod2 with respect to Mod1 (and treat Mod1 values as 100%) and draw bars. This way, we can compare how small Mod2 values are wrt Mod1 values and all different fields can comfortably sit in the same chart (max y value is 100). On top of the bar, mention the actual values.

Is there any other classic way of doing this? Also, how can I do the above mentioned idea using python matplotlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example given in the [appropriate section of the matplotlib tutorial by Nicolas P. Rougier](http://www.loria.fr/~rougier/teaching/matplotlib/#bar-plots), a quick solution would be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

mod1 = np.array([ 468, 28000, 800000000 ])
mod2 = np.array([ 162, 2000, 228000000 ])

proc = mod2.astype(float) / mod1.astype(float)

for ii, bar in enumerate(proc):
    plt.bar(ii, bar)
    plt.text(ii + 0.4, bar + 0.01, "%.2f" % bar, ha='center', va='bottom')
plt.ylim(0, 1.0)
plt.show()
```

Axis ticks, colors etc. you can then easily fine tune according to your need.